# Operator in a dual vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an operator in a vector space V, then how can it be shown that (A)* is the corresponding operator in the dual vector space of V.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because it is defined to be so... unless you have a novel definition of $A^*$, if so, what is it?

Comment: It's more helpful to first check that if $A: V \rightarrow W$ then $A^{*}:W'\rightarrow V'$. (Retrace the definitions). Then your special case follows.